# ASP.NET Core build docker image having shared libraries

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm working in a microservice environemnt where there are shared libraries between these microservices.

These libraries are stored in a different location on the disk, a "shared" location, and are directly referenced by these microservices.

In a .csproj of such a microservice you would see something like this.

```
<ItemGroup>
   <ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Shared1.csproj" />
<ItemGropu>
```

Now in each of these microservices I have a dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY . .
COPY ../../../Users/boris/Desktop/shared/Shared/Shared/Shared.csproj .
RUN dotnet restore "WebUi.csproj"

WORKDIR /src/.
RUN dotnet build "WebUi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "WebUi.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
RUN ls
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "WebUi.dll"]
```

when building a image

```
docker build -f dockerfile .
```

I'm getting

> ERROR [build 4/7] COPY ..\..\..\Users\boris\Desktop\shared\Shared\Shared\Shared.csproj .
>
> [build 4/7] COPY
> ......\Users\boris\Desktop\shared\Shared\Shared\Shared.csproj .:
> failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to build LLB:
> failed to compute cache key:
> "/..\..\..\Users\boris\Desktop\shared\Shared\Shared\Shared.csproj"
> not found: not found PS C:.demos\hangfire-dashboard\WebUi> docker
> build -f .\dockerfile -t web . [+] Building 0.2s (10/18)

I'm thinking it's because of the build context, but not sure.

Any ideas on how can I fix this ?

Comment: it looks your dockrfile not able to resolve the path `..\..\..\Users\boris\Desktop\shared\Shared\Shared\Shared.csproj`. You can run single stage build to test and then combine all to multi-stage build.

Answer (score 0):

Ok first thing first rename the `dockerfile` to `Dockerfile`. Next up is the path correct in the first place? I assume your `csproj` exists in the same folder as your `Dockerfile` and in your `csproj` you use    `<ProjectReference Include="..\..\..\Shared1.csproj" />` whereas in the docker file you use `../../../Users/boris/Desktop/shared/Shared/Shared/Shared.csproj` so if the csproj AND the Dockerfile exist in the same directory the path is simply incorrect.

Comment: why dockerfile need rename to Dockerfile?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath sanity check had an issue which seems to be fixed with that for me. Just making sure its not some funky behavior. But the root of the problem seems to be the incorrect path you have supplied which is not correctly relative. Try adding a .txt and COPY that in the folder above the csproj

Comment: dockerfile need not rename to Dockerfile